# How does a preposition interfere with the intransitive/transitive usage of the verb "beckon"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

> She indicated or beckoned for him to retrace his steps and come in.

I came across the above piece probably written on an online English newspaper, but I'm not sure.

1. Is *for* correct after *beckoned*?
2. How does *for* interfere with the intransitiveness of that verb in this sentence?

Comment: What do you mean by "the transitiveness of that verb"?

Comment: The for preposition doesn't seem to serve a purpose here. See the sentence without the preposition. 'She indicated or beckoned him to retrace his steps and come in'.

Comment: @Mist, yes, when I wrote the question I was wondered if the transitive usage of "beckon" were compatible with a preposition just after it.

Comment: @Mist, however, since I'm not so good in English language, nor in grammar of any language, included the mine, I'm not sure if in that sentence "beckon" is used as a transitive verb :)

Answer (score 5):

*For [PERSON-objective case] to [VERB]* clauses like this are often used to express a desired purpose or result; this is equivalent to *that he should retrace &c*.

You might replace *beckoned* here with *gestured* or *motioned* or *stamped her foot* or anything of the sort.

As you surmise, *beckon* is here used *intransitively*; *him*, although the subject of *to retrace*, takes the objective case as the object of the preposition *for*, not as the indirect object of *beckon*.

Comment: I'm curious to know how different they are in both sentences "I beckoned him to retrace his steps" and "I beckoned for him to retrace his steps". I surmises the former says "I directly gave a signal to him to retrace his steps", but the latter says "I gave a signal to someone and the someone passed on my signal to him". To sum up, I think whether I beckoned directly or indirectly is the main difference between them.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois No. *For* in these cases acts as the subordinator introducing an infinitival clause, just as *that* is the subordinator for finite clauses, and like *that* it is commonly omitted with complement clauses. Its presence or absence doesn't affect the sense.

Comment: Excuse me for not having checked on my comment carefully before commenting it. There was a mistake in conveying my thought on the former sentence. I get to rethink them as the former says "I directly gave a signal to him so as to have him retrace his steps", but the latter says "I gave a signal to someone so as to have the someone have him retrace his steps". On this second thought, am I grasping the sematical difference correctly?

Comment: @EvaristeGalois The version with *for* **permits** an 'indirect' interpretation, but does not **entail** it. The recipient of the gesture is not specified or limited... By the same token, however, the version without *for* **implicates** direct communication, but does not **entail** it. For instance, if we read that "Eisenhower ordered troops to Little Rock" we do not suggest that Eisenhower issued the order personally to the troops of the 101st Airborne (in fact he issued the order to the Army Chief of Staff).